# Add node name in java jung

Tags: java, graph, graphics, jung, jung2

I implemented some graph algoritms and I want to show a draw of them. I used Jung 2.0

I want to add a name to a node. I managed how to write around the edges, but I want to show the name of a node also.

Here is my code:

```
Graph<Integer, String> graph3 = new DelegateForest<Integer, String>();

        graph3.addVertex(1);
        graph3.addVertex(2);
        graph3.addVertex(3);

        graph3.addEdge("RAD-A", 1, 2);
        graph3.addEdge("RAD-B", 1, 3);

        Layout<Integer, String> layout3 = new TreeLayout<Integer, String>((Forest<Integer, String>) graph3);
        VisualizationViewer<Integer, String> vv3 = new  VisualizationViewer<Integer,String>(layout3);

        Transformer<String, String> transformer3 = new Transformer<String, String>() {

            @Override 
            public String transform(String arg0){
                return arg0;
            }
        };

        vv3.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(transformer3);

        transformer3 = new Transformer<String, String>() {
            @Override 
            public String transform(String arg0){
                return arg0;
            }
        };

        final DefaultModalGraphMouse<String,Number> graphMouse3 = new DefaultModalGraphMouse<String,Number>();
        vv3.setGraphMouse(graphMouse3);
        graphMouse3.setMode(ModalGraphMouse.Mode.PICKING);


        JFrame frame3 = new JFrame("Pas 3");
        frame3.getContentPane().add(vv3);
        frame3.pack();
        frame3.setSize(350, 300);
        frame3.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: you are almost there!! same as edgeLabel... you need to do vertexLAbel...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there... you need to do the same as you did with the edges...

for the edges you did something like:

```
 vv3.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(transformer3);
```

for the Nodes is the same... you need to **setVertexLabelTransformer**

add this segment to your code..

```
  Transformer<Integer, String> transformer = new Transformer<Integer, String>() {

    @Override
    public String transform(Integer arg0) {
    return arg0.toString();
    }

};
vv3.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(transformer);
```

## Edit:

you need to adapt the generic map in order to hold the Integer, String...

at the esd you will get somthing like

[image]

Comment: I tried what you said but it does not work, I get error at setVertexLabelTransformer, I tried others suggested fixes and I get the same result.

Comment: yeap... I see, you need to use a Trasnformer integer, String and not String String as I wrote...

Comment: now i gave a try and is working fine... I updated the answer and added a screenshot